# frequent restart of Solr required. Otherwise user gets 500 error - no available shards for solr query?

Tags: search, solr, alfresco

Using Solr 6 with Alfresco 6.2.2. Solr needs to be restarted otherwise an error is generated. The User gets a message like: framework.exception.ApiDefault, statusCode: 500 checking into the Alfresco logs, I find a corresponding error message:

ERROR: org.alfresco.rest.api.search.SearchApiWebscript : org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrQueryHttpClient.executeQuery(...)

on the next line also see this error with the same timestamp:

ERROR: org.alfresco.repo.search.impl.solr.SolrClientUtil: No available shards for solr query of store workspace://SpacesStore - trying non-dynamic configuration

Our solr index is not sharded. Does anyone know what this means? Any ideas how to fix the error? A restart of Solr is a short term solution.

****** additional comments ******

not finding a directly correlated error message in the solr log, like with corresponding timestamp and logid. What I do find is the following error message:

WARN  (SolrTrackingPool-archive-SpacesStore-0-ContentTracker-6) [   ] o.a.s.t.AbstractWorkerRunnable Index tracking batch hit an unrecoverable error
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 11148343 GetTextContentResponse return status is 500
at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getTextContent(SOLRAPIClient.java:1119)
at org.alfresco.solr.SolrInformationServer.addContentPropertyToDocUsingAlfrescoRepository(SolrInformationServer.java:3387)
at org.alfresco.solr.SolrInformationServer.addContentToDoc(SolrInformationServer.java:3374)
at org.alfresco.solr.SolrInformationServer.updateContentToIndexAndCache(SolrInformationServer.java:3306)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ContentTracker$ContentIndexWorkerRunnable.doWork(ContentTracker.java:154)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractWorkerRunnable.run(AbstractWorkerRunnable.java:45)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Does this error message mean anything?

using ACS 6.2.2, Solr 6, Search Services 1.4.3, solr spec 6.6.5. Solr has its own two node cluster. ACS also has it's own two node cluster.

The issue seems to happen everyday. When the issue happens, the user gets an error message when they try to search. The error message says it's a 500 error, framework.exception.ApiDefault.

Comment: With the few info you share it's not possible to help you. Please share any exception in the solr log like OOM and tell us about your environment like: alfresco search service version, JVM configuration, number of nodes, number of connected clients ... When does the issue arise and how does the system behave then (log, memory, threads, ...)

Comment: I added more info. There doesn't seems to be a direct error message related to the problem in the solr log. It's almost like the problem already exists and the user runs into it when they make a search query and get a 500 error as a result.